# Merge attributes of points and lines using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a point vector-layer and a line vector layer. All points of the point layer are positioned on the lines (railway lines) of the line layer. I would like to add the attributes of the line layer to the appropriate data record of each point in the point layer by a geo-calculation (analogous to a geo-calculation of points within polygons).

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

As far I can see the each point of the point layer has to be transformed with an appropriate buffer (new point layer with buffer). Then after the buffered point layer can be joined by location with the line layer.

Comment: You're correct, applying a buffer to the point layer creates a **polygon** layer which can then be used in conjunction with a _join_ function with a line layer.