# Export network layer to a shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, network, linestring, points-to-line

To continue from this question about [the format of a .csv file with network data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242069/csv-format-for-a-transport-network).

I have two layers now: 1) layer with the coordinates (X,Y) of some nodes, and 2) layer that represents the lines connecting this coordinates (the .csv that contains that lines is in `WKT` with `LINESTRING` representing the lines). Both layers are displayed well within QGIS.

Now, I want to create a shapefile with these two layers. I tried to select the two layers and `Save As>` in `ESRI Shapefile format`. However, the new shapefile only contains the coordinates of the nodes, so I can only visualise the nodes, not the lines.

I don't see any option to do that. What do I need to do (if possible)? Is there any plug-in to do so? Any Python API that I can use?

Comment: "Now, I want to create a shapefile with these two layers" : do u mean u want to mix the two geometry types (points and lines) in a single layer ? QGIS won't allow that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post: [How to merge attributes of points and lines in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131837/qgis-how-to-merge-attributes-of-points-and-lines)

Essentially, you need to use the buffer tool (Vector--> Geoprocessing Tools --> Buffer) to create polygons for each of your points.

After that, you should be able to join the two layers spatially. If not, you could also try creating a buffer around your lines as well and then merging the two buffered layers.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I also find a plug in called LinePlotter (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/LinePlotter/) which exports line coordinates (4 columns with Xo,Yo, Xf,Yf into a shape file